# Long Delay Running The Very First AWS CLI Command In Windows EC2 Moved To New Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

**Context**:-

I am setting up a windows server 2022 ec2 in a test aws account with all it's required software and configuration, then imaging it and sharing it to another aws account to launch it there.

Then there is a short powershell script that runs at windows startup to pull in cloudformation stack export values to populate environment variables for the applications' environment-specific configuration e.g. s3 bucket names.

**Issue**:-

The very first aws cli describe stack command to run experiences a long delay to complete even though it does eventually return the correct value - it takes approx 3 minutes.

```
aws cloudformation --debug --region eu-west-1 describe-stacks --stack-name SystemResources  --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='OutboundDataFilesBucketName'].OutputValue" --output text
```

All subsequent describe stack calls return in expected timeframes of about 2 seconds - even after rebooting the ec2 in the new account, the first call returns in under 2 secs, so it seems that this issue applies only to the very first call made by the instance after it is launched.

I tested with a different cli command and it also had the same behaviour so it doesn't seem to be command-specific.

**Debug Output**:-

I turned on cli debug with the --debug flag and got the following for the slow first call (snipped)

```
aws : 2023-02-21 09:45:23,000 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/2.9.3 Python/3.9.11 
Windows/10 exe/AMD64
2023-02-21 09:45:23,001 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['cloudformation', 
'--debug', '--region', 'eu-west-1', 'describe-stacks', '--stack-name', 'SystemResources', '--query', 
"Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='OutboundDataFilesBucketName'].OutputValue", '--output', 'text']
2023-02-21 09:48:14,874 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler 
<function add_s3 at 0x000001C7AEC77790>
2023-02-21 09:48:14,874 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler 
<function add_ddb at 0x000001C7AEACD5E0>
...snipped...
2023-02-21 09:48:46,351 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.cloudformation.DescribeStacks: 
calling handler <bound method RetryQuotaChecker.release_retry_quota of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryQuotaChecker 
object at 0x000001C7AF4207F0>>
```

and the following for the second call (snipped)

```
aws : 2023-02-21 09:48:47,225 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/2.9.3 Python/3.9.11 
Windows/10 exe/AMD64
2023-02-21 09:48:47,225 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['cloudformation', 
'--debug', '--region', 'eu-west-1', 'describe-stacks', '--stack-name', 'SystemResources', '--query', 
"Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='OutboundDataFilesBucketName'].OutputValue", '--output', 'text']
2023-02-21 09:48:47,294 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.main: calling handler 
<function add_s3 at 0x0000015CE5257790>
...snipped...
2023-02-21 09:48:49,500 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.cloudformation.DescribeStacks: 
calling handler <bound method RetryQuotaChecker.release_retry_quota of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryQuotaChecker 
object at 0x0000015CE5A007F0>>
```

Unfortunately, the delay occurs right at the beginning and from what i can see, there is nothing in the debug output to indicate what's causing it.

My gut feeling says networking is to blame here somehow, maybe a one-time-coz-it-just-realised-it-was-in-a-different-vpc "reconfiguration" is taking place, but i have no idea if this is right or where to look.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with a call that retrieves a parameter in the parameter store. It is currently being investigated by AWS. I also think it is a networking issue, but I have no idea how to troubleshoot it further. In my situation it happens after a reboot of the EC2 instance, and it is a script that is run via cfn-init.